# How to capture stderr of a bash keyword (e.g. time)?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, time, stderr, shell-builtin

I want to time reading bash history and put the result into a variable. 
Unfortunately, `time` (which is a shell keyword) prints the result to `stderr`, and apparently redirecting `stderr` from shell keywords doesn't work the same as redirecting regular command output. In other words,

```
foo=$(time history -r 2>&1)
```

doesn't work (`foo` variable is empty, output is printed to terminal). How can I capture the output of `time` keyword?

*Note: since `history` is a shell builtin, I cannot use external `time` command (i.e. `/usr/bin/time`) - I have to use `time` keyword in bash.*

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
foo=$((time history -r) 2>&1)
```

Placing the command in a `()` and redirect its `stderr` to `stdout`

---

Example:

```
$ foo=$((time history -r) 2>&1)
$ echo $foo
real 0m0.001s user 0m0.000s sys 0m0.000s
$
```

Comment: or with just `{ time history -r; }` instead of `( )`, it doesn't need a subshell in particular