# built-in time not formatting correctly in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a script for competitive programming judging and here is part of the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMEFORMAT=%S

if [ $1 = "-cpp" ]; then
    output1=$(g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -fsanitize=address -lm -s -x c++ b.cpp && ./a.out < input1)
    expected1=$(< output1)
    time1=$(time g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -fsanitize=address -lm -s -x c++ b.cpp && ./a.out < input1)
    if [[ -z "$expected" ]]; then
        echo "Test Case #1 - Passed! Time: ${time1} sec"
    elif [ $output1 = $expected1 ]; then
        echo "Test Case #1 - Passed."
    else
        echo "Test Case #1 - Failed (check 'dump1.log' for details)."
    fi
fi
```

The output for the C++ program is `15`. The output of the bash script is:

```
0.172
Test Case #1 - Passed! Time: 15 sec
```

It prints the time output above the actual point of concatenation. And in the place of concatenation, it prints the actual C++ output. I am extremely new to bash so I don't know what is going on.

Comment: The output from `time` (which is your shell's builtin `time` function, not `/usr/bin/time`) is going to standard error, while your `time=$(time g++ ...)` is capturing the C++ program's ordinary output. I don't see where  `$expected` gets defined at all.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: ... (cont.) see for example [How to capture stderr of a bash keyword (e.g. time)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429547/how-to-capture-stderr-of-a-bash-keyword-e-g-time) and more generally [How to measure time of program execution and store that inside a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12068/how-to-measure-time-of-program-execution-and-store-that-inside-a-variable)

Comment: I changed it so that I don't need /usr/bin/time anymore, is there still a method of formatting built in time?

Comment: @VJZGamingHD you *have* successfully formatted the builtin time (hence why you get `0.172` instead of the default `real xxx` / `user xxx` / `sys xxx`). What you have *not* done is captured it in the `time1` variable, for the reasons explained in the linked answers.

Comment: @steeldriver For some reason doing `2>&1 1>/dev/null` worked. Can you explain why I have to append that to the end of the command in the solutions so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score -3):

By simply calling `time`, you're making use of the `bash` builtin. Check this with `type -a time`.

To use the `time` program, use the full path, `/usr/bin/time`.

Read `man time bash`.

Comment: Why is `man time` relevant here? That gives the manual for the binary `/usr/bin/time` (or whatever is installed), not for the builtin. Did you mean "read `help time`"? And how is this answering the OP's question about the output they are seeing?